# Facing issues when I try to build .Net project using NUGet

Tags: .net, jenkins, nuget, devops

I am getting below error when I try to build the .NET project using NUGet. I am not able to install .net 4.5.2 since 4.7.1 is already installed in my system. I can't even uninstall 4.7.1 since it comes with Windows 10

> C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\amd64\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1098,5):
>   error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework
>   ".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" were not found. To resolve this,
>   install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or
>   retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you
>   have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be
>   resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in
>   place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be
>   correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
>   [C:\Users\majid.jenkins\workspace\DotNetFreeStyle\SeleniumNUnitParam\SeleniumNUnitParam.csproj]

Answer (score 2):

You need to install a targeting pack / developer pack for 4.5.2, not the 4.5.2 framework.

see https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/all under "Developer Pack"

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. Please accepting answers that solve your problem.